# rails activerecord - distinct counter cache implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these tables:

`broadcast
id
name`

`email
id
broadcast_id
user_id
subject`

`email_open
id
email_id
user_id`

I want to keep a count of the email_open records in my `broadcast` table.

Is the most efficient way of doing this by having a `broadcast_id` in my `email_open` table? If it is.. then I know I can just do this in my `email_open` model:

`belongs_to :broadcast, counter_cache: => true`

Then, I add a `email_open_count` to my broadcast table... but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without doing this.

Also, multiple users can have repeated records in `email_open`.. how do I make the count be of distinct `user_id`?

For example, `user_id` 1 can open an email 5 times but I just want the `email_open_count` to be 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So as per your example, if user_id 1 can open an email 5 times but You just want the email_open_count to be 1.You can the same user_id to email or whichever table you want only if that user opens an email but if the user has already open don't save it again.